# Copper or Aluminum flashing

Tags: roofing, copper, flashing

Which is a better option between Aluminum flashing v/s Copper flashing ? Just spoke to a roofing company, they said copper flashing may spoil/change color of shingles (due to rain) and aluminum flashing may be better option. Not sure how true this is.
Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: Where are you in relation to large bodies of salt water? I ask because aluminum (particularly *thin* aluminum) performs terribly near the coast where I live, due to salty ocean mist/fog/spray. I am talking like up to a 1/4 mile from the coast...

Comment: My location is northern NJ no where near to the coast.

Comment: Only reason to use aluminum instead of copper is cost.  Go price out a roll of aluminum flashing, then do the same for the same amount of copper flashing.

Comment: Aluminum I used for brackets on my deck corroded through in about 15 years ; pay more for copper.

Answer (score 1):

Although some may say this is an opinion but copper will outlast aluminum 10:1
Copper over years will have a patina that is either green or brown depending on the conditions. Aluminum if not coated will turn a dull tint and pit over time. Depending where the flashing is used it will also prevent mold growth.

As an example of long lasting I have worked on 100+ year old homes that had copper gutters and flashings that were still in great shape.  I cannot say I have ever seen 50 year old gutters or flashings made of aluminum.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of aluminum staining asphalt shingles. I do know that copper will slowly release a compound (copper?) that will wash down when it rains and deter/kill algae that will grow on the shadier part of the roof.

Both hold up very well to weather and time. I think copper is longer lived of the two, but depending on the gauge or thickness both will out last the roof shingles. Copper may be more expensive of the two.